# Slicing small 2D array from large 2D array

Tags: excel, vba

After studying in different website, I tried to extract one row or column from a 2D array with following code:

```
smallArray = Application.Index(LargeArray, RowA, 0) Or
smallArray = Application.Index(LargeArray, 0, ColA)
```

And extract few rows or columns from large array with following code something like this:

```
smallArray = Application.Index(LargeArray, Array(2,3,4), 0) Or
smallArray = Application.Index(LargeArray, 0, Array(2,3,4))
```

However, when I pratice myself with a programs like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RandomNumber() 'Generate 100 numbers
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 10
            Randomize
            Cells(i, j) = Int(Rnd * 1000)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

```
Sub Testing() 'Extract 2 Rows
    Dim TestingArray(1 To 10, 1 To 10)
    Dim TestingArray2()
    Dim arrayElement
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 10
            TestingArray(i, j) = Cells(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    TestingArray2 = Application.Index(TestingArray, Array(2, 3), 0)
    For Each arrayElement In TestingArray2
        Debug.Print arrayElement
    Next arrayElement
End Sub
```

I suppose 20 numbers will be obtained.

However, only two numbers are obtained. How should I edit my code? Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what columns you want returned.

For example, if you want all 10 columns, you could do:

```
TestingArray2 = Application.Index(TestingArray, Array(2, 3), Application.Transpose(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)))
```

This returns a 2D array (2 columns x 10 rows), with the 20 values you're looking for

If you want the column list to be dynamic, you can just define an array beforehand, and use that in the Application.Index statement

```
Dim colArr(1 To 57, 1 To 1) As Integer
For i = 1 To 57
    colArr(i, 1) = i
Next i

TestingArray2 = Application.Index(TestingArray, Array(2, 3), colArr)
```

Comment: I finally get the results I want. Thank you very much, Josh.

Comment: I have a follow up question, is it possible to simplify the part after "Transpose", ie., Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)? As in my real situation, I have 57 columns. It will be long writing from 1 to 57. Thank you.

Comment: @TingFungLi Sure, just define an array beforehand with however many columns you have, and use that in the Application.Index statement. I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, you help me a lot with what I am self-learning. I have a big step forward with my program.